# Point android emulator to local domain

Tags: java, android, tomcat, localhost, dotcms

I apologize in advance, I'm not sure what category this question fits into, if you do know, please tell me and i'll update the tags.

I've got a very puzzling problem. I've got an android application that I want to use to make REST API calls to the dotCMS Content Management system.

Now a Sample REST call is
        http://**localhost**/api/content/render/false...

But for some strange reason, this rest call fails.
        http://**127.0.0.1**/api/content/render/false... 
It seems to me that the CMS is bound to **localhost**, but not **127.0.0.1**. 
I'm assuming that 10.0.2.2 redirects to 127.0.0.1 hence my android application can't work. Is there a way to force the android emulator to call **localhost** instead of 127.0.0.1.
Alternatively is there way to bind my web application to 127.0.0.1 it comes bundled with a tomcat server.

Comment: I has before run android emulator to local server and this work for me without problem, In my case I edit (Windows) `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add my own record as `127.0.0.1  mywebbpage.my` and then use the new DNS name `mywebbpage.my`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, it looks like my Android application didn't have internet access. the app works now.